# Magento 2.1 : Pager Issue using Controller for frontend

Tags: controllers, magento-2.1, pager

I use below code in block, so pager is working perfect.

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        parent::_prepareLayout();
        if ($this->modelFactory->create()) {
            // create pager block for collection
            $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager');

            $pager->setLimit(2)->setCollection($this->getmodelCollection());
            $this->setChild('pager', $pager);// set pager block in layout
        }
        return $this;
    } 

public function getmodelCollection()
    {
        $q = $this->getRequest()->getParam('p', false);
        $limit = 2;

        $Collection = $this->modelFactory->create();
        $Collection->setPageSize($limit)
                      ->setCurPage($q);
        return $Collection;

    }
```

I try to use below code in controller, But not working. So please if any one know give me answer.

```
public function execute()
    {
        $pager = $this->layoutFactory->create()
                      ->createBlock('Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager');
        $pagerTemp = $pager->setLimit(2)->setCollection($this->getmodelCollection());
        $pagerTemp->setTemplate('html/pager.phtml');

        $resultJson = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);
        $resultJson->setData($pager);
        return $resultJson;
    }

public function getmodelCollection()
    {
        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id', false);
        if($this->getRequest()->getParam('p', false)){
            $q = $this->getRequest()->getParam('p', false); 
        }else{
            $q = 1; 
        }
        $limit = 2;

        $Collection = $this->modelFactory->create();
        $Collection->addFieldToFilter('category', $id);
        $Collection->setPageSize($limit)
                      ->setCurPage($q);
        return $Collection;
    }
```

Comment: Hello, please help me for above question. Tell me how to i can using controller?